# Issues with installing Skype on Windows 7 32-bit

Tags: windows-7, skype

My Toshiba laptop is a 32-bit with Windows 7. I am trying to install Skype but when I do I get a message saying that the program is not 32-bit, but I downloaded a 32-bit Skype.

So I don't know what to do?  Suggestions?

Comment: Can you please provide the URL where you downloaded it from?

Comment: I think you should download "the" 32-bit Skype, not just "a" 32-bit Skype. :)

Comment: You could try from this URL  http://pack.google.com/intl/en-gb/pack_installer.html

Answer (score 1):

When Windows reports a program file you downloaded is not a proper 32-bit executable, it usually means the download was **terminated before it could truly finish** - be it network or server disconnection - you have an incomplete file.

Attempt to download the file again. Take note of the reported file size (usually reported by the server); that you an idea if you have a complete copy later. e.g. if the installer was reported to be 6MB and it ends up only 1.8MB, then it most certainly isn't complete.